# Optimal strategy for prime number tower game

Tags: algorithm

**Consider the following game:**

You have a tower of N cubes. Each turn, the player can take from the tower only prime number, or power of prime number of cubes.
The winner it the last player who plays, meaning the last player to take prime number (or power of prime number) of cubes and there are no more cubes left.

Notes:

1) The run time for each turn need to be minimal.

2) There is no limit for numbers of turns

**The goal:**

a) Find an algorithm to win the game and also to determine if we need to be the first player or the second player, when there is only one tower.

b) same as a, but now we have 2 towers with different number of cubes.

**Example:**
if we have the number N=6, if we play first:

we can take 1, but player-2 will take 5 and win

we can take 2, but player-2 will take 4 and win (2 is prime number and power of 2)

we can take 3, but player-2 will take 3 and win

we can take 4, but player-2 will take 2 and win

we can take 5, but player-2 will take 1 and win

Therefor in this case the algorithm should determine that we must play second, and in this specific case we can choose to drop any amount of cubes we want.

Comment: read about Goldbach’s conjecture

Comment: @juvian If they are cooperating, that means that the game will be short.  But the goal is to figure out how to not cooperate.  Which is more complex.

Answer (score 3):

The multiple pile version is a finite additive game, in that each tower is a separate game, people can choose which one to play in next, and the games are guaranteed to terminate in a finite number of steps with a clear victor.  All additive games can be reduced to [Nim](http://www.archimedes-lab.org/How_to_Solve/Win_at_Nim.html).

Specifically the nim score of losing immediately is `0`, winning immediately is `1`, and otherwise a single tower of size `n` has the smallest possible nim score that you *can't* reach in one move, where possible nim scores are drawn from `0, 1, 2, ...`.

This allows us to recursively calculate nim scores for a single tower.  The winning strategy will be to try to always give the other person a score of `0`, and eventually you will make them lose.  Note that if you're given a position with a nim score that is greater than `0`, you can always find a move that gives the other person a score of `0` (if there was no way to get `0`, then your nim score would have been `0`).  So if you've been given a position with a score of `0` and the other person plays correctly, you will always get a score of `0` and eventually we lose.

Now here is the basic result about additive games.  If you can calculate nim scores for each of multiple towers, the nim score of the combination is just the `xor` of the individual nim scores.

So here are the first few nim scores.

```
0:  0 (you just lost)
1:  1 (nim(1-1) = 0)
2:  2 (nim(2-2) = 0, nim(2-1) = 1)
3:  3 (nim(3-3) = 0, nim(3-2) = 1, nim(3-1) = 2)
4:  4 (nim(4-4) = 0, nim(4-3) = 1, nim(4-2) = 2, nim(4-1) = 3)
5:  5 (nim(5-5) = 0, nim(5-4) = 1, nim(5-3) = 2, nim(5-2) = 3, nim(5-1) = 4)
6:  0 (can't get 0)
7:  1 (nim(7-7) = 0)
8:  2 (nim(8-8) = 0, nim(8-7) = 1)
9:  3 (nim(9-9) = 0, nim(9-8) = 1, nim(9-7) = 2)
10: 4 (nim(10 - 4) = 0, nim(10-9) = 2, nim(10-8) = 2, nim(10-7) = 3)
```

And so on.  It is easy to calculate this recursively.  Memoize, and it will be `O(n**2 / log(n))`  (For each of `n` numbers, construct the set of nim values that you could reach after all `O(n / log(n))` possible moves, then start counting from `0` up until after no more than `O(n / log(n))` possible values you've found the first that is not achievable.)

To actually play it, you should store not only the nim score of the tower, but a lookup for how to get all of the better nim values that can be achieved from it.  In a single tower version, that lets you immediately know how to play.  In the multi-tower version it is slightly more complicated.  When you're handed a position that has a non-zero nim score you should look for a tower whose nim score has a 1 in the leading binary digit of the score.  You want to move with that tower to make its new nim score be the xor of the other towers.  This new score will always be smaller than its current nim score, and therefore you will be able to make the move and hand back a 0 score.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still don't understand how to convert this game to Nim format, You haven't mentioned anything about prime number or power of prime number. Bit confused.. thanks

Comment: @EldarShalev The set of possible moves from a single tower with `n` elements is the set of prime powers that can be subtracted from it.  This lets the nim score of a single tower be calculated recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution- 
You need always keep the number in the tower to be modulo 6 equal 0 so the rival can't take prime number (or power of prime number) of cubes.

For 2 towers, you need that both of the towers will be equally modulo, means that they both modulo 6 need to be the same.